Using (existing) lower version of gcc for compilation instead of downgrading it
I was trying to compile AMBER (an MD simulation software) from source with CUDA support and the following error occurs:
[ 52%] Building NVCC (Device) object AmberTools/src/quick/src/libxc/maple2c_device/CMakeFiles/xc_cuda.dir/__/__/cuda/xc_cuda_generated_gpu_getxc.cu.o 
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83, 
                from <command-line>: 
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:132:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 12 are not supported! The nvcc flag '-allow-unsupported-compiler' can be used to override thi
s version check; however, using an unsupported host compiler may cause compilation failure or incorrect run time execution. Use at your own risk. 
 132 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 12 are not supported! The nvcc flag '-allow-unsupported-compiler' can be used to override this version check; however, using an un
supported host compiler may cause compilation failure or incorrect run time execution. Use at your own risk. 
     |  ^~~~~ 
CMake Error at xc_cuda_generated_gpu_getxc.cu.o.RELEASE.cmake:218 (message): 
 Error generating 
 /home/chikako/ambers/amber24_src/build/AmberTools/src/quick/src/libxc/maple2c_device/CMakeFiles/xc_cuda.dir/__/__/cuda/./xc_cuda_generated_gpu_getxc.cu.o 

Which quite obviously led me to think of downgrading gcc (v13), but as I checked in this answer CMake: unsupported GNU version -- gcc versions later than 8 are not supported, I could as well be modifying the run_cmake file analogous to what that answer produced:
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-8

Since I do have gcc-12 from /usr/bin/. However, my makefile looks like:
 cmake $AMBER_PREFIX/amber24_src \ 
   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$AMBER_PREFIX/amber24 \ 
   -DCOMPILER=GNU  \ 
   -DMPI=FALSE -DCUDA=TRUE -DINSTALL_TESTS=TRUE \ 
   -DDOWNLOAD_MINICONDA=TRUE \ 
   2>&1 | tee  cmake.log

where the DCOMPILER=GNU caused some confusion. What is meant by choosing GNU instead of a path to compiler(s)? I am aware that during installation g++ was also used, somewhere else without a problem.

The COMPILER option is defined by the project itself: cmake-cpptraj/AmberCompilerConfig.cmake:26. Note sure why they introduced it: CMake itself allows to set the compiler to any value and automatically detects it properties.
Since you want to set the compiler manually, you probably need to set COMPILER option to AUTO or MANUAL.
Note, that since you explicitly specify a path to C compiler, you are better to specify paths for C++ and Fortran compilers too, so they will be of the same version.
